# error using XML in sql query

Tags: sql

query is some thing like 
update table set configXML='XML' where...

here in XML i have a tag, which contains

```
Url="javascript:OpenEntityEditor(**'../Entity/EntityEditor.aspx?CNodeID={0}'+','+'resizable=yes,maximize=1'+','+'{0}'**);"
```

in above line, bond area is throwing error. How pass it as it is? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

single quote (') is not allowed in sql query more than once so if there is requirement to use (') more than once then just replace (') with 2 single quotes (''). for example :-

```
Url="javascript:OpenEntityEditor(''../Entity/EntityEditor.aspx?CNodeID={0}'',''resizable=yes,maximize=1'',''{0}'');"
```